# Не работает owl-carousel при натягивании на wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, owl-carousel

Сверстал сайт с каруселью owl-carousel. На оригинальном файле html всё работает более чем, но при переносе на wordpress карусели просто нет. Подключил все нужные css и script через function.php, но если код с запуском карусели лежит не в index.php то карусели нет. Когда  проверял и скрипт запуска поместил в саму разметку страницы все заработало. Подключение файлика скрипта проверил, просто alert он выводит, но карусель не запускает.

Вот так добавляю скрипты и стили в functions.php(Это не все что я добавляю, только часть которая относится к проблеме)

```
define("LUCID_THEME_DIR", get_template_directory_uri());
define("LUCID_IMG_DIR", LUCID_THEME_DIR."/src/img");
define("LUCID_OWL_DIR", LUCID_THEME_DIR."/src/owlcarousel");
wp_enqueue_script('owl_carousel_script', LUCID_OWL_DIR."/owl.carousel.min.js");
wp_enqueue_script('main_script', LUCID_JS_DIR."/script.js");
wp_enqueue_style("owl_carousel", LUCID_OWL_DIR."/assets/owl.carousel.min.css");
wp_enqueue_style("owl_carousel_theme", LUCID_OWL_DIR."/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css");
```

Вот так инициализирую карусель

```
let owl = $('.owl-carousel');
let body = $("body");
owl.owlCarousel({
loop:true,
items:1,
autoplay:true,
autoplayTimeout:4000,
autoplayHoverPause:true,
autoplaySpeed:1000,
dots:true,
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});
```

С jquery проблем нет, noConflict убран и в консоль ошибок не выдаёт. Карусель работает только если скрипт находится в index.php, из подключаемых файлов не работает.

Comment: Покажите, как и что вы подключаете. Без кода - вопрос ни о чём. И сразу почитайте https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось довольно просто, перечитывая https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script подумал что нужно подключить скрипты в футер. Прописал вот это в functions.php и все заработало. (последний параметр $in_footer отвечает за помещение в футер)

```
wp_enqueue_script('main_script', LUCID_JS_DIR."/script.js", array(), false, true);
```

Comment: при подключеии нужно указывать зависимости, в данном случае нет никакой гарантии что ваш скрипт снова не подключится быстрее за owl